# A question about integral convolution and real valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let
$$F, G: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
be two real smooth functions such that
$$G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}H(y)F(x-y)dy,$$
for a complex function
$$H:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}.$$

> Suppose now that $F(x)\ge 0$ and $G(x)\ge 0$ for all real $x$. Does it imply that $H(x)\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ for all $x$?

It seems that the answer is positive, but I can't prove it.

Regards

Comment: Is $G$ real or complex valued?

Comment: @ElliotG He/She mentioned $G(x)\geq 0$ which is a subset of real set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true for every class of functions $H$. The reason is that, due to smoothness of $F$, we have
\begin{equation}
\int H(y) F(x-y) {\rm d} y = \int \tilde{H}(y) F(x-y) {\rm d} y ,
\end{equation}
where $H(x)$ and $\tilde{H}(x)$ are different only in a zero Lebesgue measure set. Hence, we simply can make the value of $H(x)$ negative without changing $G(x)$.